# How can I fake virtual variadic function templates in C++?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, dynamic-dispatch

The following code is impossible:

```
struct poly_base {
    template <typename... ARGS>
    virtual void operator()(ARGS&&... args) = 0;
};

template <typename DATA>
struct poly_derived : public poly_base {
    DATA data;
    template <typename... ARGS>
    void operator()(ARGS&&... args) override {
        data(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
    }
};
```

In what ways can I fake such functionality without relying on the dynamic polymorphism provided by virtual functions? Most importantly, how can I do this without constraining the types of arguments accepted by `operator()`, except to those supported by the intersection of all `DATA`?

If the combinations of `ARGS&&...` needed were known ahead of time, I'd store the necessary function pointers in `poly_base`, or declare the necessary pure virtual functions. But how can I do this without constraining the argument types?

Were such a thing possible, I'd expect the compiler to generate a vtable with the union of all `poly_base::operator()` overloads invoked in all translation units for each `DATA` with which `poly_derived` is instantiated. How can I fake such a thing myself using variadic templates, function pointers, and template variables?

Clarification: I don't want to type-erase `ARGS`. They should be known to the caller and to the callee. I only want to erase `DATA`.

Comment: Do you really need `poly_base` ? can't you use template function instead with `poly_derived<DATA>` directly ?

Comment: The function where I need this is already templatized over `ARGS...`. Unfortunately, I want to use it on elements of a container of`poly_base` that actually stores different `DATA` types. In more traditional C++ this would be a vector of abstract base pointers that point to different derived types.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.  You don't.

The set of arguments that a single type supports in C++ is Halt-complete; you couldn't even do this for a **single** `DATA` type where you type erase all valid arguments in a known table.

On top of that, the set of types derived from a class is not available anywhere with dynamic linking, it is not even known at link time.

Comment: I don't want to erase `ARGS`. I only want to erase `DATA`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `C` variadic args can fix the `ABI` problem, but I don't know whether it can be used with keyword `virtual`.